# Given a set D = {a+b•| a,b ∈ $\mathbb{R}$} and a made-up binary operation, in a quadratic equation.

Tags: quadratics, binary-operations

Given a set D = {a+b•| a,b ∈ $\mathbb{R}$}

And a made-up binary operation on D is defined as follows: (a+b•)(c+d•)= ac+(ad+bc)•

For example, (2+3•)(-3+5•)= (-6+1•)
You are not allowed to combine (-6+1•) into -5• because they are not like terms. you are allowed to combine like terms, however, like this:
(a+b•)+(c+d•) = a+c+(b+d•)

So the question is:
Solve the quadratic equation $x^2$-2x+12•=0

I'm very confused about the 12• and binary operation part. Should the quadratic formula be used here? How would you solve it?

Comment: What, and why, is that dot to the right of some numbers?

Comment: the dot doesn't represent multiplication or anything, it's just a symbol to differentiate like terms. it's similar to how 2q is different from 2 so you can't combine 2q+2, but q doesn't represent any value. So in this case the • is used to create the binary operation

Comment: @Berci sorry about that, I fixed it. It's just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the $\bullet$ rather by $q$, even if that doesn't represent any *real number* as value. So that, $q:=0+1\!\bullet$.

Now we have $q^2=q\cdot q=0+0\bullet=0$, and basically that implies the whole multiplication (just the same way as $i^2=-1$ and linearity generates the multiplication for complex numbers).

We have to solve $x^2-2x+12q=0$. Write up $x$ as $x=a+bq$ then we have
$x^2=a^2+2abq$, so what is needed is:
$$a^2-2a+(2ab-2b)q=-12q$$
Looking at the 'coordinates' on both sides, we need $a^2-2a=0$ and $2b(a-1)=-12$.

Comment: am I allowed to solve those two "coordinates" to find a = 0 and plug a into the second equation to find b=6 ? (excluding all the q's because the q's are confusing to solve with and I can just add them in later.) I'm confused as to what x would end up being, since it represents (a+b). As in, what would the final answer be for x

Comment: Yes, either $a=0$ or $a=2$ and the corresponding $b$ values are $6$ and $-6$, meaning two solutions: $x=6\bullet$ and $x=2-6\bullet$. (For example, for $x=6\bullet$, its square is $0$, so $x^2-2x=-2x=-12\bullet$ indeed.)

Comment: a similar question that relates to the system but not to the quadratic equation. Is it possible to use the created binary operation to get an answer of (5+0q) where q stands in for ∙ ? I've been trying for awhile but 5 seems prime in this system, though I know it is definitely not.